# Extracting strings and messages from react app via regex?

Tags: reactjs, localization

We wrote a react application that has its strings and messages directly inside the source code. Now we would like to localize it. Reading [this](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/extracting-translations) at the beginning seemed like there were tools to extract strings from source code, generate keys, and put them into external files.

However, now after taking a closer look, and also trying them, I am realising that those tools only extract strings that are marked with some kind of function or component wrap (such as `t()`, or `<Trans></Trans>`).

Since we have hundreds of those strings, we need to automate some of that process. I figured that a lot of work can be accomplished by using regex search replace to wrap strings in `<Trans></Trans>` or `t()`. But there is not a single regex that matches all cases. So I am pretty sure this has been done before and even though I put some effort into some googling and chatGpting, I can't find any.
I think I might be missing something.
A regex collection would help a lot already.

Any guidance is highly appreciated!

Comment: The amount of work to refine your regex is equal to setting up a script to properly parse your source files and update the corresponding text nodes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy automated solution for this. Strings can appear in the application in a variety of ways (as a variable, inside the JSX part, inside the vanilla JS part, as a constant, and so on), so it's hard to find a single solution for all these cases.

In addition, it depends on the specific case which component of the internationalization library should be used, so the automatic replacement won't work.

I would recommend the following correct way to migrate to the internationalization library (as an example I will use [**Lingui**](https://lingui.dev/)).

Lingui uses a similar approach with the `<Trans>`, `i18n.t` wrappers around the string. It also provides an [**ESLint plugin**](https://github.com/lingui/eslint-plugin) to help you find common Lingui usage errors in your code.

In the present case, we need this rule especially:

> [`no-unlocalized-strings`](https://github.com/lingui/eslint-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#no-unlocalized-strings) - Checks if the code doesn't contain strings/templates/jsxText that should be wrapped in `<Trans>` or `i18n`.

So thanks to this plugin you can easily **detect all "unlocalized" strings**.

It's also highly recommended to use the [Pseudolocalization](https://lingui.dev/guides/pseudolocalization) feature.

> Pseudolocalization is a method for testing the internationalization aspects of your application by replacing your strings with altered versions and maintaining string readability

With this feature, the developer will see all the application texts that are not yet localizable.

Comment: Well, thanks for explaining, but doing this work string by string manually would just be stupid. Regex can be a big help already.

Comment: @stoefln there are a lot of cases (vanilla JS, JSX part, plurals, selects, strings with placeholders, etc.) when we should decide which i18n component to use. So it's not possible to just replace everything with regex, it always requires developer attention and sometimes even some refactoring.

Comment: I already made a lot of progress with just a couple of regex patterns that are quite generically useable for JSX

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` across a codebase are not always very strictly defined, thus obtaining a super-efficient regex doesn't seem very possible. However, I reached at a regex that might be close enough to proceed with but still would require a manual walkthrough.

**Regex:** `>\s*([^<]+)\s*<`

**Replace with:** `><Trans>$1</Trans><`

**Explanation:**

- `\s*`: Matches any number of whitespace characters.
- `([^<]+)`: Matches any number of characters that are not `<`

**Note:** I intentionally didn't put the new line character checks as that was causing some other syntax to be included as well.

For example:
starting: **`() => {...`** and ending: **`<div....`** was being detected by that

**Bonus tip:** You can leverage some AI tools where you can provide some chunks of your code (or whole components) and instruct it to convert any strings inside JSX to be wrapped as per need. It would still require a manual review but I guess it would be a significantly decent option than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that regexes are the easiest way to accomplish this. The reason is that your code has a lot of elements that look like strings, but that you don't really want to touch. Some examples:

```
import React from "react";

<div className="component-app">
```

You can try to add complex rule to your regex to solve all corner cases, but it will require a lot of time.

For this kind of problems there are more specialized tools such as Babel that can parse your code into an Abstract Syntax Tree, apply transformations to it based on context, then parse the AST back into javascript code.

Check out this project, it does exactly what you want, using Babel transformations istead of regex:
https://github.com/Ghost---Shadow/i18nize-react